# How to solve SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert records in database but i'm getting error

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away in D:\xampp\htdocs\staff-activity\add_program.php:67 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\staff-activity\add_program.php(67): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\staff-activity\add_program.php on line 67

here's my code

```
if(isset($_POST['upload2'])){
        $sname = $_POST['sname'];
        $designation = $_POST['designation'];
        $department = $_POST['department'];
        $image = addslashes(file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
        $dob = $_POST['dob'];
        $doji = $_POST['doji'];
        $experiance = $_POST['experiance'];
        $qualification = $_POST['qualification'];

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $info = $_POST['info'];

        $submit_query = "INSERT INTO staff VALUES ( :sname, :designation, :info, :dob, :doji, :qualification, :experiance, :papers, :books,
         :memberships, :awards, :email, :departments, :images);";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($submit_query);
        $stmt->bindValue(':sname',$sname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':designation',$designation, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':info',$info, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':dob',$dob, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':doji',$doji, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':qualification',$qualification, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt->bindValue(':experiance',$experiance, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt->bindValue(':papers',(trim($_POST['papers']) == "") ? $_POST['papers'] : NULL, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':books',(trim($_POST['books']) == "") ? $_POST['books'] : NULL, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt->bindValue(':memberships',(trim($_POST['memberships']) == "") ? $_POST['memberships'] : NULL, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':awards',(trim($_POST['awards']) == "") ? $_POST['awards'] : NULL, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':email',$email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':departments',$department, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':images',$image, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
}
```

Any ideas of how could I solve it?

I already tried passing values through execute array

Thanks.

Comment: That means something caused the server to crash. A single `INSERT` would not normally do this, you need to check the server's log file to see what went wrong.

Comment: It has been answered Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133030/php-mysql-pdo-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Mysql PDO: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133030/php-mysql-pdo-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)